# Default applications for Android emulator almost empty

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-emulator

I am developing an android application in my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I have installed Android wear ARM system image for the emulator, and it is running well. But There seems no default application in it to handle some activities like loading image, surfing the net... and so on. What am I missing and how do I activate the default applications for the emulator.

Here is a snapshot of the android emulator with blank screen.

[image: Android Emulator On Ubuntu 14.04]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that using the `Google APIs` system image comes with more apps included. I usually use that one rather than `SDK Platform`.

[image: sdk manager]

Comment: Thanks roarster for the quick reply. When you try with the SDK Platform's system image, was the emulator blank like mine?

Comment: I'm not sure which screen you're on. I'm sure I must have had some apps, but I can't fully remember.